# No results when calling UDF within select statement

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Using PHP 7.1, PDO, I am trying to run a query to a remote SQL Server Database, which all connects fine and am able to run queries, accept when using User-Defined Functions.

Statement runs fine when ran directly on the SQL Server Database, just via PHP is an issue.

I have ran this via PHP without the User-Defined Function and works fine, I get results.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

```
$pdo = new \PDO(
            sprintf(
                "dblib:host=%s;dbname=%s",
                $server,
                $database
            ),
            $user,
            $pass
        );


$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "
    select 
        acCode AS 'Ac Code', 
        acCompany AS 'Company Name',
        myDBName.myFunctionName(2020, 0, acCode) AS 'Balance'
    from 
        myDBName.CUSTSUPP
    where 
        acCustSupp = 'C' 
    and
        myDBName.myFunctionName(2020, 0, acCode) > 0
    order by 
        acCode";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Please, post your PHP code. And probably `myDBName.myFunctionName(2020, 0, acCode) > 0` should be `dbo.myFunctionName(2020, 0, acCode) > 0` or `myDBName..myFunctionName(2020, 0, acCode) > 0`.With `PHP` you can easily select the `myDBName` database. Thanks.

Comment: Using a scalar UDF in your WHERE clause is a recipe for terribly slow code. It will have to read the whole table every time, avoid any parallel processing and receive the performance hit of simply using a scalar UDF.

Comment: I have change the original post with updated code. Thanks

Comment: Using string literal as column aliases has been deprecated for a long time. https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases

Answer (score 1):

UDFs are executed within a SELECT statement by specifying the owner, name and parameters. In your case, if `myDBName` is not the owner name, you need to change it with `dbo` or actual owner. Also, you need to include exception handling to get the actual error message.

Your may try with the following code, based on the code in your question:

```
<?php

// PDO object
$server = "myserver";
$database = "myDBName";
$user = "myuser":
$pass = "mypassword";
try
    $pdo = new \PDO(
            sprintf(
                "dblib:host=%s;dbname=%s",
                $server,
                $database
            ),
            $user,
            $pass
        );
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("Error connecting. ".$e->getMessage());
}

// Statement
try
    $query = "
        select 
            acCode AS [Ac Code], 
            acCompany AS [Company Name],
            dbo.myFunctionName(2020, 0, acCode) AS [Balance]
        from 
            CUSTSUPP
        where 
            acCustSupp = 'C' 
        and
            dbo.myFunctionName(2020, 0, acCode) > 0
        order by 
            acCode";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // ... Additional code here
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("Error executing query. ".$e->getMessage());
}

// End
$statement = null;
$pdo = null;
?>
```

Comment: Hi,I have tried your suggestions but still no luck. By changing the myDBName i get the following error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4121 Cannot find either column "username" or the user-defined function or aggregate "xxxxUser.EntCustBalance", or the name is ambiguous. [4121] (severity 16) [(null)]26/09/2019 15:17:35 - Exception

Comment: If it were an issue with the owner, then would there not a be a PDO exception thrown to suggest that? It's strange I get no errors with the original code.

Comment: @Kal If it's possible, check for errors and post them. Thanks.

Comment: I've checked all available areas that I can think where there maybe be apache, php errors and there is nothing. Limited experience with SQL Server, the log files that I can see on there didn't show anything.

Comment: @Kal You need to be sure, that the user `$user` has the exeute permission on this function and this function exists in the `$database` database. You are using SQL authentication to connect to SQL Server and this is also a possible reason for this unexpected behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely sure the $user user has execute permissions on the function. Function definitely exists within the $database database. I logged into SQL Server, using the same credentials and executed the SQL statement and worked fine.

Comment: @Kal, I still think that it is probably a database context or case sensitivity issue. Try to recreate the function using `USE [database]; CREATE FUNCTION owner.myFunctionName() ...`. Thanks.